# how can find a record in mongodb by null value

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

there are such documents in a collection:

```
  {name:'abc', age:'22',job:'writer', place: 'place1',tag:['a','v']},
  {name:'def', age:'24',job:'no job', place: 'place1',tag:['a','f']},
  {name:'ghi', age:'22',job:'writer', place: 'place3',tag:['d','v']},
  {name:'jklm', age:'22',job:'editor', place: 'place4',tag:['a','d']},
```

i need to search by below condition(user enter details)

```
searchKey{ 
 sk_age:'22',
 sk_job:['writer','editor']
 sk_place:null,
 sk_tag:null 
}
```

'place and tag user not entered '
i am writing mongodb quires like below , but this not work, how can find **correctly**

```
db.user.find( { 
        age:sk_age,
        job:sk_job,
        place:sk_place,
        tag:sk_tag,
      } ).toArray()
```

*i expect || i need below listed recorders*

```
{name:'abc', age:'22',job:'writer', place: 'place1',tag:['a','v']},
{name:'ghi', age:'22',job:'writer', place: 'place3',tag:['d','v']},
{name:'jklm', age:'22',job:'editor', place: 'place4',tag:['a','d']},
```

Comment: What happens with your current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `$in` operator and also check whether fields are not null something like

```
const query = {
  age:sk_age,
  job: {'$in': sk_job}
}
if (sk_place !== null) {
  query.place = sk_place;
}
if (sk_tag !== null) {
  query.tag = sk_tag;
}

db.user.find(query).toArray()
```